# Memory Allocation Runtime Error in C

Tags: c, memory-management, runtime-error

I have created the following code, a simple brute force program for printable ascii. The user passes in the parameters for starting passphrase length and ending passphrase length. When my program runs I get the following error:

**Input:**

```
~$ Enter START length & END length ex:(8 10): 2 3
```

**Output:**

```
... (more output above)
~|
~}
~~

*** glibc detected *** ./wordgen: double free or corruption (out): 0x0916e008 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6cbe1)[0x874be1]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x6e50b)[0x87650b]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(cfree+0x6d)[0x87969d]
./wordgen[0x80486f4]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xe7)[0x81ee37]
./wordgen[0x8048471]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-0012a000 r-xp 00000000 08:06 3408733    /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1Aborted
```

**Valgrind Output:**

```
==11050== Invalid read of size 1
==11050==    at 0x804866F: main (wordgen.c:37)
==11050==  Address 0x41a2027 is 1 bytes before a block of size 3 alloc'd
==11050==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==11050==    by 0x8048600: main (wordgen.c:28)
==11050== 
==11050== Invalid write of size 1
==11050==    at 0x8048675: main (wordgen.c:37)
==11050==  Address 0x41a2027 is 1 bytes before a block of size 3 alloc'd
==11050==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==11050==    by 0x8048600: main (wordgen.c:28)
==11050== 
==11050== Invalid read of size 1
==11050==    at 0x8048689: main (wordgen.c:38)
==11050==  Address 0x41a2027 is 1 bytes before a block of size 3 alloc'd
==11050==    at 0x4026864: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
==11050==    by 0x8048600: main (wordgen.c:28)
==11050==
```

**C Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int  sLen = 1;
  int  eLen = 0;

  printf("Enter START length & END length ex:(8 10): ");
  scanf("%d %d", &sLen, &eLen);
  int cLen = sLen;
  while (cLen <= eLen) {

    /* Allocate Memory for String  & Initialize */
    char *outStr = malloc(cLen + 1);
    memset(outStr, ' ', cLen);
    outStr[cLen] = 0;

    int outerControl = 1;
    while (outerControl == 1) {
      int cMod = 1;
      int innerControl = 1;
      while(innerControl == 1) {
        outStr[cLen-cMod] += 1;
        if((int)outStr[cLen-cMod] == 127) {
          //Exit Condition Where The Error Occurred
          if(cLen - cMod == 0) { outerControl = 0;  } 
          outStr[cLen-cMod] = 32;
          cMod += 1;
        }
        else { innerControl = 0; }
      }
      printf("%s\n",outStr);
    }
    free(outStr); // Possible source of Error?
    cLen += 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I am new to C programming and am completely baffled by this error. What does it mean? How did I create my program incorrectly? I'm assuming it has something to do with memory management...

Comment: Try to compile with `-Wall -g` parameters and use `valgrind`.

Comment: I did use valgrind, it suppressed the runtime error. When I ran without valgrind the error occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
while(innerControl == 1) {
  printf("%d %d\n", cLen, cMod);
  outStr[cLen-cMod] += 1;                       // <-- this here
  if((int)outStr[cLen-cMod] == 127) {
    //Exit Condition Where The Error Occurred
    if(cLen - cMod == 0) { outerControl = 0;  }
    outStr[cLen-cMod] = 32;
    cMod += 1;
  }
  else { innerControl = 0; }
}
```

At some point, `cMod` grows to be larger than `cLen`, so you're accessing `outStr` out of its bounds (i.e.: `outStr[-1]`). This behavior is undefined.

This condition:

```
if(cLen - cMod == 0) { outerControl = 0;  }
```

...seems to be there to prevent that, but will only be executed if `(int)outStr[cLen-cMod] == 127`. You probably should add something like:

```
if (cMod > cLen)
    break;

outStr[cLen-cMod] += 1;
```

Comment: I literally just figured this out, came back to create the answer, and you had posted it ;) Changed condition to `if(cLen - cMod == 0) { outerControl = 0; innerControl = 0; }`

Comment: @awashburn: You're mistaking me for someone else, I did not edit the answer. ;-) Anyway, glad you found it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You free outStr on each pass of your `while (cLen <= eLen)` loop, so it would work correctly only if `eLen - cLen` < 1 ;)

Update: sorry, I was wrong -- you malloc it at each pass.

I tried your program and it worked without any error on my mac. Try to use valgrind to find out what is happening.